# How to join these three tables in an efficient way?

Tags: mysql, database, join

I am having a database design, where every user has one machine, containing 7 components. Every component has a level. Think of browsergames, where you have to level up different things.

Here is a picture from the user table. I need to take one user row out of it.

[image: User table]

Join it with this table, that resolves colum name to ID for components.

[image: Machine types]

And then select the 7 colums consisting of matching level and ID matching the user row.

[image: Machine upgrades]

The user table will have a huge number of rows, so the join has to be done after the where clause.

I never really looked at joins but here I am with a very complex one and I don't know where to start. What would be an appropriate mysql query and can you elaborate a bit about how it works? This is for a learning project so every hint to a working solution is very much appreciated!

**Edit:**

Here is an example use case:

The User with a UserID of 3 is logged in. The row for his ID states that his energy component is at level 0 and his cpu component is at level 1. Resolving these names we find that energy has a ComponentID of 1 and cpu has a ComponentID of 3. We match these with the upgrades table and find, that the component with ComponentID of 1 and level of 0 has an output of 15 and the ComponentID of 3 with a level of 1 has an output of 8.

```
+------+------+-----+----------+------+----+
|UserID|type  |level|level_name|output|etc.|
+------+------+-----+----------+------+----+
|3     |energy|0    |Knopfzelle|15    |... |
+------+------+-----+----------+------+----+
|3     |cpu   |1    |Register  |8     |... |
+------+------+-----+----------+------+----+
```

It would even be fine to remove the user column...

**Edit2:**

Thanks to all the comments under this question, I have decided to review my database structure and will start a new question when new problems will come up. If you have a solution for this particular *bad_design* user case, I would love to see it even if it is bad practice.

Comment: need a clearer view of the schema to do any help

Comment: @rjv what do you mean by a clearer view, can you give me an example so I can provide you with it?

Comment: the columns of the table do not make any sense to me :) where do you map the user to a machine?

Comment: I'll edit the question to provide an example

Comment: the problem you're having is that the 'cpu', 'gpu' etc are columns in the first table. it would be probably easier to resolve that if you would use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

Comment: @user3012759 I think it would be unreasonable to use your method when there are only seven components and every user has every one of them one time. It would even be fine to map them statically, as energy will always have the ID of 1...

Comment: well, if you insist on having them as columns then you will have to select them explicitly.

Comment: @rjv added an example with a possible result table

Comment: The problem is... if you don't normalize the db as user3012759 suggests, then you will have to build complex queries with CASE statements. And even worse... the engine will not be able to optimize access very well, as columns are not and cannot be indexed (but rows can) ;)

Comment: @Kostronor. I would suggest you rethink your design. You need that junction table to effectively query. This design is very bad. And you should not have any problem making normal joins once you have the junction table in place. Do nto worry about the join being before the where caluse, databases rearrange how they do things internally for the best way to get the data.  WHat is critical is to have good indexes on the join fields which you can't have with the current design becasue you literally have nothing to join on.

Comment: @all thanks for your comments! I will remodel my structure and come back here :)

Comment: @HLGEM @Frazz @user3012759 Would a table like this (http://i.imgur.com/F4oBCJs.jpg) replacing `hacks_machine` help?

Comment: Yes... that is the way. Define the foreign keys and the uniqueness of (userId, componentId).

Comment: @Frazz thanks! I tried the new design with inner join on these three tables and it worked out of the box!